# To what extent is it possible to understand if a bacteria can produce a protein? (in silico only!)

Tags: dna, bioinformatics, proteins, bacteriology

I have to answer a question about a sub-task of my thesis: **Can the bacteria *X* produce the protein *Y*?**

I searched of course Google and BLAST. There is no data supporting that this specific bacteria ever produced this protein sequence.

However, my thesis supervisor wants me to go deeper<sup>[1]</sup>, but I don't know how to do it *in silico* in a way to offer a proper answer.

What I'm thinking of doing with the data at hand is to create a DB on localhost with all the versions of the protein listed in BLAST (*I'm using ruby, not sure how can I fetch all this data in FASTA format yet, but I'll figure it out*), and all the strains of the bacteria listed in BLAST and perform a [fuzzy string matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching).

That's like brute-forcing. After I have a possible score I can get the closest score of them all, study it a bit and then submit my answer.

Is there any other way to attack this problem in order to submit a proper, at least partially polished answer?

NOTE: I don't have access to any lab, any *experiment* must be performed in silico.

[1] My supervisor believes that IF this bacteria needed this protein it WOULD be able to to produce it at will without undergoing mutations. And since his level of dedication and knowledge revolving molecular biology is scary, it's kind of hard to believe that he is wrong.

Comment: I am coming from the wet lab - and my experience is that you can clone practically every gene into a fitting vector and express is in bacteria. You need the right regulatory sequences (promotors and so on), but it is possible. The question, if this protein is produced in big amount and if it soluble is something different. Also many proteins are modified posttranslationally which is something bacteria cannot do.

Comment: Hello Chris. I'm not interested in to cloning anything but thanks for the info.

Comment: I understood that. I simply wanted to add some comment on the practical side of this problem, this might help you as well?

Comment: Of course @Chris, I will mention to my paper that it's possible to achieve the wanted result with cloning. Without your comment I wouldn't had that extra paragraph, which will make my paper better anyway :-) ... So thank you again!

Comment: To be clear: You want an algorithm to match if the given fasta can be produced by the bacteria genome?

Comment: @DevashishDas No, I already have a [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/amatch) with a list of fuzzy matching algorithms. I'd like to know if there's any other approach worth pursuing except that. NOTE: Any comment on the algorithms would be good also: **Hamming, Jaro, JaroWinkler, Levenshtein, LongestSubsequence, LongestSubstring, PairDistance, Sellers**. These are the ones supported by the library I'm going to use.

Comment: Are you talking about whether the Bacterium naturally produces a protein or whether it could express a particular protein?

Comment: @JackAidley Whether if needed it could express a particular protein (at any quantity).

Comment: you can predict an ORF from DNA/RNA sequence but you cannot be sure if the protein is produced. You can either do LC-MS to see if signature peptides are produced or use molecular bio experiments as Chris suggested. You can also tag your sequence with GFP and see if it expresses.

Comment: you can download proteomics data (if available) for your bacteria and search for the signature peptides that your protein-x is likely to produce.

Comment: If you're just looking at whether a protein can be expressed, you might be misunderstanding your supervisor. The set of proteins _needed_ by a given bacteria is a tiny, tiny subset of the set of proteins that bacteria is capable of producing, provided the gene coding for the protein is provided to the bacteria. If instead you're curious about whether a bacteria can express a given protein without any changes to its genome, there are plenty of proteins that are coded for in the genome but only expressed under specific circumstances. I'd look into promoters if I were you for more info on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem will finally boil down to searching your sequence in the Blast databases. Performing Blast seems to be probably the best way to find out if your bacteria has that specific protein expressed or not. If you could not find it in the nearest species using Blast, then try running PSI-BLAST, which would return you distant homologs, by which you can see if your protein is expressed in the other bacterial species.

Comment: I'm on to something using blast (I dropped out the idea of writing my own script to do this as soon as I played around with BLAST). I know that E. Coli can produce my protein (it's documented) at protein level. I couldn't find a perfect match thought, I've found a 74% positive match. Then searched about Desulfovibrio and found a 75% positive match (for a specific strain). I think it's enough, I can't take the risk to answer the question in a definitive way but, it's enough data to give some food for thought and possible direction. Comments are more than welcomed! Ty!